# Passenger not accepting environment variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, environment-variables, passenger

Someone previously answered that you need to set variables directly in bashrc file. I'm on an Ubuntu VPS, and I followed this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-rails-and-nginx-with-passenger-on-ubuntu

Tailing the nginx logfile, I get this output:

```
App 2435 stderr: [ 2014-11-12 22:24:39.9703 2451/0x0000000109d610(Worker 1) utils.rb:84 ]: *** Exception RuntimeError in Rack application object (Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml`) (process 2451, thread 0x0000000109d610(Worker 1)):
App 2435 stderr:    from /home/XXXXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/application.rb:462:in `validate_secret_key_config!'
App 2435 stderr:    from /home/XXXXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/application.rb:195:in `env_config'
App 2435 stderr:    from /home/XXXXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:510:in `call'
App 2435 stderr:    from /home/XXXXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
App 2435 stderr:    from /home/XXXXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/passenger-4.0.53/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:74:in `process_request'
App 2435 stderr:    from /home/XXXXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/passenger-4.0.53/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:141:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
App 2435 stderr:    from /home/XXXXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/passenger-4.0.53/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:109:in `main_loop'
App 2435 stderr:    from /home/XXXXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/passenger-4.0.53/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:455:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
```

This error occurs every time I load the web page. The page is a 502 Bad Gateway. My nginx config file:

```
user                          XXXXX;
worker_processes              2;
worker_priority               -5;

error_log                     /home/rails/log/nginx.error.log  crit;

events {
    use                       epoll;
    worker_connections        1024;
}


http {
passenger_root /home/XXXXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/passenger-4.0.53;
passenger_ruby /home/XXXXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/wrappers/ruby;
server {  listen 80;  server_name rails.pt localhost;  passenger_enabled on;  root /home/rails/public;  }
}
```

The XXXXX are the server name, but I am actually using server_name rails.pt localhost; because I'm not sure what else can go there.

Performing 
echo $SECRET_KEY_BASE does echo back a key I generated.

Any advice on how to make this work? I've tried stopping and starting nginx, I've even rebooted the whole droplet a few times. The app I'm trying to run is completely blank, and was made on the droplet.